# Browserstack: how to change platform when testing on mobile devices?

Tags: python, selenium, browserstack

I've been trying to upload files to the mobile simulator that BrowserStack provides. However, I'm learning that anytime I get an error, the platform is set to Mac OSX, not Windows (where I upload the files). How do I change the platform specified by the Driver info?

Note: I'm writing tests in Python using Selenium

Here's what the error looks like:

> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (108, 458) (Session info: webview=37.0.0.0) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343837 (sessionidhere),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64)

note: sessionidhere is not what it literally stated

Answer (score 0):

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

desired_cap = {'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': 'xp', 'browser': 'IE', 'browser_version': '7.0'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://logindetailshere@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
```

On error, by clicking a nonexistent element in this case, these details are shown:

> Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=false,
>   ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, version=7, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,
>   ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false,
>   browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=about:blank,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]